# Can some one tell me what i have done wrong

Tags: java

I got a question in interview about a man who can take a step back or move double of his current distance . Considering each of them as a single move find minimum moves he can take to reach y from x.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static int Solve(int x,int y)
    {
        if(x==0)
        {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        else if(x==y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(x==1)
        {
            return 1+Solve(x*2,y);
        }
        return Math.min(1+Solve(x*2,y),1+Solve(x-1,y));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        int y=sc.nextInt();
        int z=Solve(x,y);
        System.out.print(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing, `Solve(1, 5)` will call `Solve(2, 5)` which will in turn call `Solve(1, 5)` (as an example), so you have infinite recursion.

Comment: Also Solve (x*2, y) is never ending. Your recursion logic is correct, in the sense you have the two separate cases for x*2, x-1, and call it by 1+Solve(...) I would look to changing the base cases... when the recursion should stop. Is it 1D points? If so the answer is much much easier

Comment: Ignoring java naming conventions might have cost you points. Java methods and fields begin with lower case letters (solve).

Comment: Please update your title to reflect the question you are asking. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop. At what place will Solve( x * 2, y) ever
stop ?

Assuming all this is in one axis only (1D), since you defined int x and int y. Let’s say we have x and y, if y-x is positive, that means we have to go forward. Now if y-x is odd, let’s say 7 that means we have to go 8 steps (4*2) ahead, then 1 (1 step) back. Giving us 5 steps. So we have to go

```
(((y-x) + 1)/2) + 1
```

So 7+1 = 8, we go 8 steps ahead taking double steps, then 1 more step to come back.
If it is even, then that means we can go straight ahead ! So

```
(y-x)/2
```

If y-x is negative, which means we have to go back. Only way is 1 step back (x-1), so that will just be

```
-(y-x) steps.
```

You can write the code. I like the recursion aspect for your code, but it’s an overkill if it is 1D.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a recursion-based solution is needed here.

We have two subproblems here:

1. count moves back when `from >= to`
2. otherwise count moves forward taking into account a case when difference `to - from` is odd: then 1 extra move forward is needed and 1 step back.

This can be resolved with the help of a ternary operator:

```java
public static int findMoveCount(int from, int to) {
    return from >= to ? from - to : (to - from) % 2 * 2 + (to - from)/2;
}
```